# Do integrated smart plug sockets exist?

Tags: smart-home, smart-plugs

I've seen a lot of Smart Plugs for sale online like the ones below.

The next logical step to me seems to have integrated plug sockets in the wall as the smart plugs are quite bulky. But I can't for the life of me find any...

Do they exist? If so, where? If not, why?

[image: Smart plug array]

Comment: I'm going to guess and say no on the grounds that they wouldn't meet the electrical spec (or that you would need a physical on/off switch as well as a soft on/off switch that could be remote controlled)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @hardillb. The need for a physical switch i wouldn't imagine being an issue as that's exactly how the set up is with smart plugs. In that regard it would be no different.

Maybe electrical spec is the issue, it's not something i know about myself.

Comment: Beware of the security implications of even suing them. Read [this](https://www.helpnetsecurity.com/2018/08/23/hacking-smart-plugs/) and Google for more

Comment: @Mawg that's great news for me, thanks for that link - finally the second-generation Wemo switches are hackable - now I can customise the OS a little bit, and surely someone with more free time than me will release an up-to-date OpenWRT for it soon. I might then take my Wemo switches out of their personal WLAN (where they can do no harm) :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, "smart sockets" seem to be readily available on the market. Some examples include:

- **UK**: [Lightwave](https://lightwaverf.com/smart-power). Particularly the [LW260](https://lightwaverf.com/smart-power/1-gang-socket) 1 gang socket, [LW270](https://lightwaverf.com/smart-power/2-gang-socket) 2 gang socket and the [L42](https://lightwaverf.com/smart-power/2-gang-smart-socket) 2 gang socket seem to be what you were looking for—a smart plug socket without any bulky extrusions. With regard to legality, Lightwave say, *"All Lightwave devices are safe and legal to DIY retrofit in your own home"*
- **USA**: The [iDevices Wall Outlet](https://store.idevicesinc.com/idevices-wall-outlet/), which claims to be *"the only Wi-Fi® enabled in-wall outlet featuring HomeKit™, Alexa and the Google Assistant compatibility"*.

I'm certain that there are several other products on the market; they tend to be advertised as either "smart sockets" or "smart (in-wall) outlets" or other words to that effect. It is worth doing your research if you do find a manufacturer to ensure that the products are safe and legal in your area.

Comment: They do exist! I knew deep down they would/should! Thank you @Aurura0001 . Not sure how every Google I did turned up nothing on these haha.

Answer (score 5):

There is also a company called "Allterco Robotics". They introduced the "Shelly". This is a very small piece of ESP8266 Hardware and some open source software.

You can place them behind your existing plugs and control your plugs via WiFi afterwards.

https://shelly.cloud/shelly1-open-source/